# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator en un select

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Utilizando oracle 11g del USUARIO.
¿Por qué me sale error cuando quiero contar 3 datos de una columna y agregarle un intervalo con otra columna y ponerlos de forma descendente?

```
select owner, count(1)
  from all_tables
  where owner = 'SYS' and ('SYSTEM') and ('SCOTT') and (LAST_ANALYZED between 01/01/2010 and 01/05/2021)
 group by desc
 group by owner;
```

--error

> ```
> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
> 00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> Error en la línea: 26, columna: 38
> ```

Comment: ¿Conocés la condición [`IN`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm)? Tenés errores de sintaxis, tanto en el `where` como en el `group by` (que además lo estás repitiendo).

Comment: `AND` no funciona como crees que funciona. Revisa la sintaxis de tu sentencia.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres obtener?

Comment: El resultado debe contar los 3 nombres de manera descendente y con un rango de fecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios errores en la consulta.

Las piezas cruciales para armar bien tu rompe-cabezas son:

1. Si quieres obtener los registros que coincidan con varios `owner`s, puedes utilizar el operador `in` o simplemente usar varios operadores `or` en el `where`, por ejemplo:

   ```
    select *
      from all_tables
     where owner in ('A', 'B', 'C')
   ```

   O su equivalente:

   ```
    select *
      from all_tables
     where owner = 'A'
        or owner = 'B'
        or owner = 'C'
   ```
2. Si quieres usar fechas en una sentencia SQL, debes ponerlas como cadenas de caracteres y utilizar la función `to_date()` para convertir dicha cadena en tipo de dato fecha, por ejemplo:

   ```
    select *
      from all_tables
     where last_analyzed between to_date('2021-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('2021-01-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
   ```

   Como puedes ver, a la función se le puede indicar explicitamente el formato de la fecha, con lo cual queda poco lugar a confusiones y los [elementos que puedes usar en el formato](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) están bien documentados.
3. Si quieres combinar varias condiciones en una consulta `where`, ten en cuenta la [precedencia de los operadores lógicos](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E49933_01/server.770/es_eql/src/ceql_expr_precedence_rules.html), pero si quieres evitar ambigüedad, puedes utilizar paréntesis, por ejemplo:

   ```
    select *
      from all_tables
     where (   owner = 'A'
            or owner = 'B'
            or owner = 'C'
           )
       and table_name like 'INV%'
   ```

   En el ejemplo, la indentación es solo para dejar más clara mi intención.

Ya te queda a ti, como ejercicio final, poner las piezas juntas para resolver el problema que tienes con la consulta de la pregunta. Dudas o comentarios, quedo al pendiente.

Comment: Gracias lo pude resolver SELECT owner,
COUNT(TABLE_NAME)as CANTIDAD_TABLAS FROM DBA_TABLES
where(OWNER in('SYS','SYSTEM','SCOTT')) AND 
(LAST_ANALYZED BETWEEN '01/01/2010' and '01/05/2021')
group by OWNER 
order by(CANTIDAD_TABLAS)desc;

Comment: Felicitaciones, esa es la idea.